# COUNT values in different columns of one table SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

For example, my table has data - 10 volunteers.
There are two types of volunteers - students and staff.
How can insert few columns in one table with this view:

COUNT(Volunteer_id), COUNT(Volunteer_id) WHERE Volunteer_type = 'Student',
COUNT(Volunteer_id WHERE Volunteer_type = 'Staff'

```
SELECT COUNT(Volunteer_id) AS "TOTAL VOLUNTEERS"
from volunteer
UNION
SELECT COUNT(Volunteer_id) AS "TOTAL VOLUNTEERS"
from volunteer
WHERE Volunteer_type = 'Staff'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(Volunteer_id) AS "TOTAL VOLUNTEERS"
from volunteer
WHERE Volunteer_type = 'Student'
```

This statements are represented as rows for now, but I want to make them columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS "Total Volunteers",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Volunteer_tpye = 'Staff' THEN 1 END) AS "Staff Volunteers",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Volunteer_tpye = 'Student' THEN 1 END) AS Student
FROM volunteers
```

Comment: Oracle shows a mistake ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: That doesn't look like Oracle syntax, and actually it doesn't really look like SQL at all. Did you mean `select count(*) as total_volunteers, .....`?

Comment: Updated for ORACLE syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @volunteer TABLE 
(Volunteer_id int 
,Volunteer_type varchar(50) )

INSERT INTO @volunteer  VALUES (1,'Staff')
INSERT INTO @volunteer  VALUES (1,'Staff')
INSERT INTO @volunteer  VALUES (1,'Staff')

INSERT INTO @volunteer  VALUES (1,'Student')
INSERT INTO @volunteer  VALUES (1,'Student')
INSERT INTO @volunteer  VALUES (1,'Student')


SELECT COUNT(Volunteer_id) AS "TOTAL VOLUNTEERS"
       ,(
           SELECT  COUNT(tb1.Volunteer_id) AS "TOTAL VOLUNTEERS"
           FROM   @volunteer AS tb1
           WHERE  tb1.Volunteer_id = tb.Volunteer_id
             AND  tb1.Volunteer_type = 'Staff'


       )
       ,(
           SELECT COUNT(volunteer_Student.Volunteer_id) AS "TOTAL VOLUNTEERS"
           FROM   @volunteer AS volunteer_Student
           WHERE  volunteer_Student.Volunteer_id = tb.Volunteer_id
             AND  volunteer_Student.Volunteer_type = 'Student'
       )
FROM   @volunteer tb
GROUP BY tb.Volunteer_id
```

Comment: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis.Where can be an error? Code looks right

Comment: There is no `@this` and `@that` in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select
  sum(t.x_all) cnt_all,
  sum(t.x_staff) cnt_staff,
  sum(t.x_student) cnt_student
from (
  select
    1 x_all,
    case when v.volunteer_type = 'Staff' then 1 else 0 end x_staff,
    case when v.volunteer_type = 'Student' then 1 else 0 end x_student
  from volunteer v
) t
```

Comment: Read and understand Felix's solution, he showed how to do this in one step. You posted a weaker solution after the better one was already posted, I don't see the point.

Comment: @mathguy Look at the timestamps. About "weaker" solutions - there are many ways one can solve this problem. This is one and I could argue it's more readable & understandable.